# HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData not have definition

Tags: .net-core

In dotnet core 6 service (class library) I am accessing `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData()` but it says it does not contains definition for `GetRouteData`.

Any help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`GetRouteData()` is an extension method in namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing`.

You have to add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have to install nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing`